# Yii2 assets bundle max folder size limit

Tags: yii2, bundle, assets

I want to theme integration in Yii2. I have a theme which have 24 MB assets folder.I'm using asset bundle.Other theme folders are created but asset folder is not created on backend/asset folder.

Comment: I try another computer and problem is solved but I want to working my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Google cache exceed over 618 MB and asset bundle is not working
I clear google cache and fixed the problem
[image]